# Simulating Data Efficiently with data.table

Tags: r, performance, memory, data.table

I am trying to simuate a new dataset from two smaller datasets. It is important for me to maintain the marginal
counts from these smaller datasets in the final dataset. Hopefully this reproducible example should explain what
I mean.

#### Build fake data

```
library(data.table) # 1.10.5
set.seed(123)
meanVal <- 40
```

#### demoDat

Here I simulate some age and gender data. Each location will always have 2 levels of gender and 100 levels of age.

```
demoDat <- CJ(with(CJ(letters,letters[1:5]), paste0(V1,V2)), c("M","F"), 0:99)
setnames(demoDat, c("Location","Gender","Age"))
demoDat[, Val := rpois(.N, meanVal)]


       Location Gender Age Val
    1:       aa      F   0  36
    2:       aa      F   1  47
    3:       aa      F   2  29
   ---                        
25998:       ze      M  97  45
25999:       ze      M  98  38
26000:       ze      M  99  39
```

#### timeDat

This code simulates the temporal data dimension. In this case, the dates are spaced out by week, but the actual data do not have to adhere to this uniformity. Weeks can be missing.

```
timeDat <- with(demoDat, CJ(unique(Location), seq(from=as.Date("2016-01-01"),by=7,length.out = 52)))
setnames(timeDat, c("Location","Date"))
totals <- demoDat[, .(Val=sum(Val)), by=.(Location)]
timeDat[totals, Val := rmultinom(1:.N, i.Val, prob=rep(1,.N)), by=.EACHI,on=.(Location)]

      Location       Date Val
   1:       aa 2016-01-01 176
   2:       aa 2016-01-08 143
   3:       aa 2016-01-15 143
  ---                        
6758:       ze 2016-12-09 165
6759:       ze 2016-12-16 142
6760:       ze 2016-12-23 156
```

#### Quick reconciliation

Each location should a `Val` column that totals to be the same in both the `demoDat` and the `timeDat` datasets.

```
timeDat[, sum(Val), by=.(Location)][order(-V1)][1:5]
#    Location   V1
# 1:       jb 8229
# 2:       xb 8223
# 3:       ad 8179
# 4:       nc 8176
# 5:       gd 8173
demoDat[, sum(Val), by=.(Location)][order(-V1)][1:5]
#    Location   V1
# 1:       jb 8229
# 2:       xb 8223
# 3:       ad 8179
# 4:       nc 8176
# 5:       gd 8173
```

#### Desired final dataset

Next, I want to create a dataset with `Age`, `Gender`, and `Date` variables. But I need to maintain my marginal sums of `Val` from the `demoDat` and `timeDat` datasets.

I have one strategy that accomplishes this task, but it takes up quite a bit of RAM. Is there another strategy I can employ that performs the expansion within each group at a time? Maybe using
`.EACHI`?

#### Expand both datasets and merge

This is the expensive part of the operation. The datasets are expanded so the number of rows is equal to the `sum(Val)`. In cases where the `sum(Val)` is `> 500,000,000`, this can be expensive. Especially since the operation is repeated for a second dataset. I am hoping to use `.EACHI` so only the data within groups are expanded, which should lower the memory footprint substantially.

```
library(pryr)
memUsed <- mem_used() 
demoDatBig <- demoDat[rep(1:.N, Val), .(Location, Gender, Age, ID=rowid(Location))]
timeDatBig <- timeDat[rep(1:.N, Val), .(Location, Date, ID=rowid(Location))]
demoDatBig[timeDatBig, Date := i.Date, on=.(Location, ID)]
finalBigDat <- demoDatBig[, .(Val=.N), by=.(Location, Gender, Age, Date)]
mem_used() - memUsed
# 47 MB
```

So this operation took 47 MB of RAM, but if I increase the `meanVal`, it increases significantly. I would like this to use as much RAM as this operation would take for the same function on the biggest `Location` and `ID` group. I think this is possible using `.EACHI`, but I am not exactly sure how.

#### Resulting data.table

```
       Location Gender Age       Date Val
    1:       aa      F   0 2016-01-01  36
    2:       aa      F   1 2016-01-01  47
    3:       aa      F   2 2016-01-01  29
    4:       aa      F   3 2016-01-01  40
    5:       aa      F   4 2016-01-01  24
   ---                                   
32430:       ze      M  96 2016-12-16   7
32431:       ze      M  96 2016-12-23  34
32432:       ze      M  97 2016-12-23  45
32433:       ze      M  98 2016-12-23  38
32434:       ze      M  99 2016-12-23  39
```

#### The solution would hopefully pass these tests

```
#### Test 1
test1 <- finalBigDat[, .(Val = sum(Val)), by=.(Location, Gender, Age)]
test1[demoDat, ValCheck := i.Val, on=.(Location, Gender, Age)]
test1[Val != ValCheck]
#Empty data.table (0 rows) of 5 cols: Location,Gender,Age,Val,ValCheck

#### Test 2
test2 <- finalBigDat[, .(Val = sum(Val)), by=.(Location, Date)]
test2[timeDat, ValCheck := i.Val, on=.(Location, Date)]
test2[Val != ValCheck]
#Empty data.table (0 rows) of 4 cols: Location,Date,Val,ValCheck
```

#### Results

I went through both solutions and tracked memory and system timings for both. Both solutions were amazing and are huge upgrades to what I currently have. @swihart's solution scales unbelieveable well to large `meanVal`, so I chose this as the accepted answer. Heather's answer will help in situations when `meanVal` is not quite as large. Both large and small `meanVal` occur frequently so I will need both.

```
   meanVal            Ans            Time      Mem    Rows
1:      40     Mike.Gahan  0.6245470 secs 44.54293   32434
2:      40 Heather Turner  0.6391492 secs 38.65355 1352000
3:      40        swihart 11.1602619 secs 66.97550 1352000
4:     400     Mike.Gahan  2.593275 secs 437.23832   32611
5:     400 Heather Turner  1.303993 secs  38.79871 1352000
6:     400        swihart 11.736836 secs  66.97550 1352000
7:    4000     Mike.Gahan 30.390986 secs 4364.51501   32629
8:    4000 Heather Turner  6.279249 secs   38.79871 1352000
9:    4000        swihart 11.427965 secs   66.97550 1352000
10:   20000     Mike.Gahan -------did not finish----------
11:   20000 Heather Turner 23.78948 secs 36.30617 1352000
12:   20000        swihart 11.53811 secs 66.97550 1352000
13:   30000     Mike.Gahan -------did not finish----------
14:   30000 Heather Turner 537.6459  secs 57.15375 1352000
15:   30000        swihart 11.970013 secs 66.97474 1352000
```

Comment: Please put numbers on "takes up quite a bit of RAM" and how much improvement you want? 10%? 90%? In particular please isolate which expression in which line is wasting RAM. See existing questions on memory-profiling. You can always fall back on disk-backed storage like HDFS if you need to.

Comment: `meanVal` should be 40, not 400, correct?

Comment: and in the `##timeDat` chunk, can `,on=.(Location)` be omitted?

Comment: For reproducibility, since all your print outs of the data.tables are with `meanVal <- 40`, consider changing back to 40 from the current 400 and update the MB.  On my machine with `meanVal <- 40` I'm getting closer to 47  MB, not the 490 MB cited.

Comment: Will the `demoDat` always have number of rows equal to  # locations x 2 levels of gender x 100 levels of age?  That is, all possible combos of levels is fixed and a 0 will appear in Val if it doesn't occur in the real world?

Comment: Yes..each location will always have 2 levels of gender and 100 levels of age.

Comment: will there always be 52 weeks ... if not, a pre-set grid of dates?

Comment: no. the time-points will not adhere to a grid.

Comment: You are not being clear with your language above - it is not the process (per se) that is taking up RAM - the RAM is being taken up by the final objects. `?mem_used` shows you the memory that is currently being used by R, not the max amount that is used by a given process. This can also be verified by using `object.size` on your "Big" data.tables - you will see that they are what is taking up your memory. So - do you want to make the act of creation more efficient, or do you want to take up less RAM with the resulting objects?

Comment: You can reduce final memory by about 20% by using factors instead. I.e. `timeDatBig <- timeDat[rep(1:.N, Val), .(Location = as.factor(Location), Date, ID=as.factor(rowid(Location)))]`. Beyond this I would suggest using SQL instead

Comment: Do you know a max number of unique dates per Location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your approach for different sizes of `meanVal`, and saw the scaling issue for the approach of generating `demoDatBig` and `timeDatBig`.  I have an approach (enclosed at bottom of this post) that generates `cartDat` -- the cartesian cross of the dates and gender-age groups that is robust to increases in `meanVal` and `sum(Val)`, as seen in this table that lists the results of `object.size()` for the data.tables being discussed:

```
| meanVal  | sum(Val) | demoDatBig (MB)  | timeDatBig (MB)  | cartDat (MB)  |
|----------|----------|------------------|------------------|---------------|
|      40  |     1e6  |            27.8  |            15.9  |          67.1 |
|     400  |     1e7  |           277.6  |           158.7  |          67.1 |
|   4,000  |     1e8  |         2,776.8  |         1,586.8  |          67.1 |
|  40,000  |     1e9  |        27,770.3  |        15,868.7  |          67.1 |
```

The key to my approach is to generate a cartesian cross between the unexpanded source data.tables `demoDat` and `timeDat`, and then use an "iterative multivariate hypergeometric sampling" (`IMHS`) scheme to preserve the margins of both source data.tables.  In order to have an R functionality for the `IMHS`, I took from CRAN the R package BiasedUrn and recompiled it so that it could handle 52 colors (in our application, Dates).  If the max number of Dates for a given location needs to be adjusted, let me know and I'll re-recompile.  Thus, the [R package BiasedUrn52 is on github](https://github.com/swihart/BiasedUrn52).

My solution passes the `test1` and `test2` and preserves the marginals.  However, it seems to distribute the gender-age marginal across more dates than OP procedure.  Allow me to elaborate:

If we take the first 5 rows of `timeDat`:

```
> head(demoDat,5)
   Location Gender Age Val
1:       aa      F   0  36
2:       aa      F   1  47
3:       aa      F   2  29
4:       aa      F   3  40
5:       aa      F   4  50
```

And the first 6 of `finalBigDat`:

```
> head(finalBigDat,6)
   Location Gender Age       Date Val
1:       aa      F   0 2016-01-01  36
2:       aa      F   1 2016-01-01  47
3:       aa      F   2 2016-01-01  29
4:       aa      F   3 2016-01-01  40
5:       aa      F   4 2016-01-01  24
6:       aa      F   4 2016-01-08  26
```

We see the entire 36 for the F-0 gender-age group was ascribed to 2016-01-01, whereas the 50 for the F-4 group was distributed across 2016-01-01 (24) and 2016-01-08 (26), but no other dates (50=24+26).

The `IMHS` method distributes the marginals across many more dates (I'm not sure if this is desired or not -- please let me know).  For instance, `IMHS` took the 36 of the F-0 group and instead of putting all 36 onto 2016-01-01 as in `finalBigDat` it spread them across more Dates (look at `seq.Draws`):

```
> cartDat[Location=='aa' & Gender=="F" & Age==0,
+         c("Location", "Gender", "Age", "Date", "seq.Draws"),
+         with=FALSE]
    Location Gender Age       Date seq.Draws
 1:       aa      F   0 2016-01-01         1
 2:       aa      F   0 2016-01-08         0
 3:       aa      F   0 2016-01-15         1
 4:       aa      F   0 2016-01-22         1
 5:       aa      F   0 2016-01-29         0
 6:       aa      F   0 2016-02-05         0
 7:       aa      F   0 2016-02-12         0
 8:       aa      F   0 2016-02-19         0
 9:       aa      F   0 2016-02-26         0
10:       aa      F   0 2016-03-04         0
11:       aa      F   0 2016-03-11         0
12:       aa      F   0 2016-03-18         0
13:       aa      F   0 2016-03-25         3
14:       aa      F   0 2016-04-01         1
15:       aa      F   0 2016-04-08         0
16:       aa      F   0 2016-04-15         0
17:       aa      F   0 2016-04-22         1
18:       aa      F   0 2016-04-29         1
19:       aa      F   0 2016-05-06         0
20:       aa      F   0 2016-05-13         2
21:       aa      F   0 2016-05-20         0
22:       aa      F   0 2016-05-27         0
23:       aa      F   0 2016-06-03         0
24:       aa      F   0 2016-06-10         0
25:       aa      F   0 2016-06-17         1
26:       aa      F   0 2016-06-24         2
27:       aa      F   0 2016-07-01         0
28:       aa      F   0 2016-07-08         0
29:       aa      F   0 2016-07-15         0
30:       aa      F   0 2016-07-22         1
31:       aa      F   0 2016-07-29         0
32:       aa      F   0 2016-08-05         1
33:       aa      F   0 2016-08-12         1
34:       aa      F   0 2016-08-19         1
35:       aa      F   0 2016-08-26         1
36:       aa      F   0 2016-09-02         1
37:       aa      F   0 2016-09-09         2
38:       aa      F   0 2016-09-16         0
39:       aa      F   0 2016-09-23         1
40:       aa      F   0 2016-09-30         0
41:       aa      F   0 2016-10-07         2
42:       aa      F   0 2016-10-14         3
43:       aa      F   0 2016-10-21         0
44:       aa      F   0 2016-10-28         1
45:       aa      F   0 2016-11-04         1
46:       aa      F   0 2016-11-11         1
47:       aa      F   0 2016-11-18         0
48:       aa      F   0 2016-11-25         0
49:       aa      F   0 2016-12-02         2
50:       aa      F   0 2016-12-09         1
51:       aa      F   0 2016-12-16         1
52:       aa      F   0 2016-12-23         1
```

The noting of the distributional differences between the OP approach and the `IMHS` `cartDat` approach is just an aside.  The marginals are preserved, as seen below.

The marginals for `timeDat` are preserved:

```
> cartDat[, sum(seq.Draws), by=.(Location, Date)]
      Location       Date  V1
   1:       aa 2016-01-01 176
   2:       aa 2016-01-08 143
   3:       aa 2016-01-15 143
   4:       aa 2016-01-22 154
   5:       aa 2016-01-29 174
  ---                        
6756:       ze 2016-11-25 169
6757:       ze 2016-12-02 148
6758:       ze 2016-12-09 165
6759:       ze 2016-12-16 142
6760:       ze 2016-12-23 156
> timeDat
      Location       Date Val
   1:       aa 2016-01-01 176
   2:       aa 2016-01-08 143
   3:       aa 2016-01-15 143
   4:       aa 2016-01-22 154
   5:       aa 2016-01-29 174
  ---                        
6756:       ze 2016-11-25 169
6757:       ze 2016-12-02 148
6758:       ze 2016-12-09 165
6759:       ze 2016-12-16 142
6760:       ze 2016-12-23 156
```

as are the marginals for `demoDat`:

```
> cartDat[, sum(seq.Draws), by=.(Location, Gender, Age)]
       Location Gender Age V1
    1:       aa      F   0 36
    2:       aa      F   1 47
    3:       aa      F   2 29
    4:       aa      F   3 40
    5:       aa      F   4 50
   ---                       
25996:       ze      M  95 48
25997:       ze      M  96 41
25998:       ze      M  97 45
25999:       ze      M  98 38
26000:       ze      M  99 39
> demoDat
       Location Gender Age Val
    1:       aa      F   0  36
    2:       aa      F   1  47
    3:       aa      F   2  29
    4:       aa      F   3  40
    5:       aa      F   4  50
   ---                        
25996:       ze      M  95  48
25997:       ze      M  96  41
25998:       ze      M  97  45
25999:       ze      M  98  38
26000:       ze      M  99  39
```

Here is the `IMHS` `cartDat` approach and some tests:

```
#Cartesian cross of demoDat and timeDat
devtools::install_github("swihart/BiasedUrn52")
library(BiasedUrn52)
setkey(timeDat, Location)
setkey(demoDat, Location, Gender, Age)
cartDat <- demoDat[timeDat, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
setkeyv(cartDat, key(demoDat))
cartDat
cartDat[,group:=.GRP,by=c("Gender", "Age") ]
cartDat[,demoDat.Val:=Val]
cartDat[,timeDat.Val:=i.Val]
setcolorder(cartDat, c("Location", 
                       "group",
                       "Gender",
                       "Age",
                       "Val",
                       "demoDat.Val",
                       "Date",
                       "timeDat.Val",
                       "i.Val"))

#Define Iterative Multivariate Hypergeometric Sampling function
imhs <- function(.N, Val, i.Val, group){

  grp.ind <- unique(group)
  num.grp <- max(group)
  grp.size <- as.numeric(table(group))

  draws <- rep(NA, length(group))
  for(grp in grp.ind){

    if(grp==1){
      draws[group==1] = rMFNCHypergeo(1, 
                                      i.Val[group==1], 
                                      Val[group==1][1], 
                                      rep(1/grp.size[grp.ind==1],grp.size[grp.ind==1])
      )
      i.Val[group==2]= i.Val[group==1]-draws[group==1]
    }else{
      draws[group==grp] = rMFNCHypergeo(1, 
                                        i.Val[group==grp], 
                                        Val[group==grp][1], 
                                        rep(1/grp.size[grp.ind==grp],grp.size[grp.ind==grp])
      )
      if(grp<=num.grp){
        i.Val[group==(grp+1)]= i.Val[group==grp]-draws[group==grp]
      }
    }

  }

  list(i.Val, draws)
}


# run it the data.table way:
cartDat[,
        c("seq.Val", "seq.Draws") := imhs(.N, demoDat.Val, timeDat.Val, group),        
        by=c("Location") ]

# take a look:
cartDat

# reconciliation
demoDat[, sum(Val), by=.(Location)][order(-V1)]
cartDat[, sum(seq.Draws), by=.(Location)][order(-V1)]

# do the checks for the margins:
cartDat[, sum(seq.Draws), by=.(Location, Date)]
timeDat
cartDat[, sum(seq.Draws), by=.(Location, Gender, Age)]
demoDat


# such different sizes due to distributing across more dates:
nrow(demoDat)
nrow(cartDat)
nrow(cartDat[seq.Draws != 0])
nrow(finalBigDat)
nrow(cartDat[seq.Draws != 0])/nrow(finalBigDat)

# attain and print object sizes for cartDat
print(object.size(cartDat), units = "Mb")
print(object.size(cartDat[seq.Draws!=0]), units="Mb")

# attain and print object sizes for demoDatBig, timeDatBig, finalBigData
print(object.size(demoDatBig), units = "Mb")
print(object.size(timeDatBig), units = "Mb")
print(object.size(finalBigDat), units = "Mb")



## (OP) The solution would pass these tests:
finalBigDat2 <- cartDat

#### Test 1 (change to sum(seq.Draws))
test1 <- finalBigDat2[, .(Val = sum(seq.Draws)), by=.(Location, Gender, Age)]
test1[demoDat, ValCheck := i.Val, on=.(Location, Gender, Age)]
test1[Val != ValCheck]
#Empty data.table (0 rows) of 5 cols: Location,Gender,Age,Val,ValCheck

#### Test 2 (change to sum(seq.Draws))
test2 <- finalBigDat2[, .(Val = sum(seq.Draws)), by=.(Location, Date)]
test2[timeDat, ValCheck := i.Val, on=.(Location, Date)]
test2[Val != ValCheck]
#Empty data.table (0 rows) of 4 cols: Location,Date,Val,ValCheck
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this to work with 104 weeks rather than just 52 weeks? Did you change the Makevars file to 52 because it would be faster?

Comment: I increased makevars from 30 to 52.  I can increase to 104.  I'll do it sometime this weekend.

Comment: No worries. I already changed it and re-compiled. I only wonder if there is a reason why that max exists? Is it dangerous if I increase that value too much? I am unsure.

Comment: I wonder too.  Maybe email Agner Fog as found in the DESCRIPTION.

Comment: Just emailed Agner. No problem in setting the max colors higher, but some functions will take a long time if the number of colors is high.

Answer (score 1):

By joining on Location and ID, your current approach matches dates to observations in the gender:age categories in a systematic way, e.g. assigning the first date to the first 176 observations (covering the first four gender:age categories and part of the fifth) and so on.

Instead you can simulate counts of each date within each gender:age category by using the `r2dtable` function from the **stats** package to simulate the two-way (gender:age):date contingency table such that the marginal totals are fixed.

First create the combinations of Gender, Age and Date within each location

```
setkey(timeDat, Location)
setkey(demoDat, Location)
finalBigDat <- demoDat[timeDat, .(Location, Gender, Age, Date),
                       allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Then apply `r2dtable` within each Location, set the row totals as the count in each gender:age category and the column totals as the count at each date:

```
setkey(finalBigDat, Location)
finalBigDat[, Val := c(r2dtable(1, demoDat[.BY, Val], timeDat[.BY, Val])[[1]]),
            by = Location]
head(finalBigDat)
#    Location Gender Age       Date Val
# 1:       aa      F   0 2016-01-01   0
# 2:       aa      F   1 2016-01-01   3
# 3:       aa      F   2 2016-01-01   2
# 4:       aa      F   3 2016-01-01   2
# 5:       aa      F   4 2016-01-01   1
# 6:       aa      F   5 2016-01-01   0
```

This passes test 1 and 2 as required. The dimensions of `finalBigDat` are always the same whatever the value of `meanVal`, however `rd2table` will take longer to run with higher `meanVal`. Here are some illustrative timings:

```
| meanVal  | sum(Val) | time (s) |
|----------|----------|----------|
|      40  |     1e6  |     0.36 | 
|    4000  |     1e8  |     7.72 |
|   20000  |     5e8  |    35.09 |
```

I did try with meanVal = 40000, but stopped the code running at about 300s, so you might run into difficulties if you want to set a high meanVal.